# Encounter GAE error whilst pushing to dev

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml

i m new to GAE and i got the following error. Wonder is it due to the app.yaml file?

```
"ERROR    2011-08-13 18:39:57,723 dev_appserver_main.py:579] Fatal error when loa
ding application configuration:
Invalid object:
Unknown url handler type.
<URLMap
    secure=default
    static_files=None
    auth_fail_action=redirect
    require_matching_file=None
    static_dir=None
    script=None
    url=/
    upload=None
    expiration=None
    position=None
    login=optional
    mime_type=None
    >
  in "app\app.yaml", line 24, column 19"
```

### app.yaml

```
application: test
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1


handlers:

# simple static web site
# static as root folder  

- url: /.*
  script: form_post.py
```

Comment: this is my app.yaml                                                                      application: test
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1


handlers:

# simple static web site
# static as root folder  

- url: /.*
  script: form_post.py

Comment: Edit it into your question formatted correctly, no one can tell what it says in that comment.

Comment: done so. have added in the app.yaml. does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says

```
in "app\app.yaml", line 24, column 19"
```

and

```
script=None
```

While the `app.yaml` you show both has the script set and doesn't have 24 lines.

So either you didn't show your whole `app.yaml` or that's not the `app.yaml` that `dev_appserver.py` is seeing. Try searching for another one and making sure the file is in the right place.

Also, check the whitespace before `script` -- apparently it has to be exactly right for things to work. If you don't have a `form_post.py` file exactly where GAE is looking for it, you will also get this error.

Comment: thanks a lot i think the app.yaml is the issue. At least i dont see the error now but some other error (ImportError: No module named webob)

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the SDK installed properly, or there's a problem with your Python installation itself.

Comment: Another vote for "please actually include the code that caused your issue, rather than a sanitized stripped down version of it".